# Minecraft server startup help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have been able to download the mincraft server file. `minecraft_server.1.7.10.jar version`

However, I have having difficulty running it. According to the tutorial, it says to run:
`-Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui` by saving it into a notepad, placing it in the same folder as the server, and double clicking it.

I did this by using the rich text document as I am on a Mac. No results.

So i tried running `-Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar`. no results.

I am stuck, and not sure what to do next. anyone help please?

UPDATE: Thanks to everyone who posted! By sorting out through identified problems and more tutorials, the server is up and running. Although I do need to work out some of the details, thanks again to everyone.

Comment: the tutorial can be found here:http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Setting_up_a_server

Comment: The [Mac OS X](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server#Mac_OS_X_instructions) instructions may be more helpful here - the configurations required for OS X are a little different.

Comment: Did you add the right file extension?

Comment: Please do not update a question by removing everything and replcing it with a staus update, i have added your admenment to the previous version

Answer (score 2):

Putting it in a rich text document is not going to run it. You do have to use the full command, `java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.1.7.10.jar nogui`, but you need to either type it into terminal or put it in a `.sh` file.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the java part.  You're supposed to run `java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.1.7.10.jar nogui`.

Comment: You also have to save with the right file extension to, which is `.sh`.